# Fix $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g\in G$, a group. The equation $x^k=g$ has the same number of solutions in $G$ as does $y^k=\phi(g)$ in $G^\prime$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Fix $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g\in G$, a group. The equation $x^k=g$ has the same number of solutions in $G$ as does $y^k=\phi(g)$ in $G^\prime$ where $\phi:G\to G^\prime$ is an isomorphism.

My attempt.

Let $x\in G^\prime$ such that $x^k=\phi(g)$, since isormophisms are surjective we know there exists an element $h\in G$ such that $\phi(h)=x$, thus $\phi(h)^k=\phi(g)$. And since isormorphisms are injective, then $\phi(h)^k=\phi(h^k)=\phi(g)$ implies $h^k=g$. Thus every solution to $x^k=\phi(g)$ in $G^\prime$ gives exactly 1 solution to $x^k=g$ in $G$.

Suppose $h\in G$ is a solution so that $h^k=g$ then $\phi(h^k)=\phi(h)^k=\phi(g)$, so $\phi(h)$ is a solution to $x^k=\phi(g)$ in $G^\prime$. Since isomorphisms are injective there is only 1 element $y\in G$ such that $\phi(y)=\phi(h)$ thus every solution to $x^k=g$ gives exactly 1 solution to $x^k=\phi(g)$ in $G^\prime$.

Since each solution in either group gives exactly 1 solution in the other, the number of solutions is preserved and thus they have the same number of solutions.

> I think I have the idea but I'm not sure my proof really explains the reasoning too well. Also is isomorphism necessary? Or is injective homomorphim sufficent?

Answer was provided in comments but I had the thought that simply by injectivity $\phi$ will map solutions in $G$ to solutions in $G^\prime$ as $x^k=g \iff \phi(x)^k=\phi(g)$. Similarly it will also map elements which are not solutions in $G$ to elements which are not solutions in $G^\prime$ as $x^k\not= g \iff \phi(x)^k\not= \phi(g)$.

This however isn't sufficient as it does not account for solutions which are present in the codomain but are not in the image of $\phi$. Thus surjectivity is necessary.

Comment: $x=g^k$ is not an element in $G'$. But we have $\phi(x)^k=\phi(g)$, and for this the claim is clear.

Comment: Yes I've changed the variables to reflect that now. The question doesn't ask to show that an isomorphism maps solutions in $G$ to solutions in $G^\prime$ but this seems to be true.

Comment: Yes, we have $y=\phi(x)$. The equation $x^k=g$ is just equivalent to $\phi(x)^k=\phi(g)$, by "relabelling" the elements of $G$ to the ones of $G'$. So everything is the same.

Comment: Right. I guess I don't need to make this argument about their being correspondence both ways as just through injectivity if $y^k\not =g$ then $\phi(y)^k\not = \phi(g)$ so I know I wont pick up additional solutions.

Comment: Bijectivity would be necessary.  For instance, consider the inclusion mapping $\phi:(\Bbb R^*,\cdot) \to (\Bbb C^*, \cdot)$.  The equation $g^2 = -1$ does not have the same number of solutions as $y^2 = \phi(-1) = -1 \in \Bbb C$.  For a finite example, the same sort of argument could be made with an injective map $\phi : \Bbb Z_2 \to \Bbb Z_4$.