# Let $H=\{\alpha \in S_7 :\alpha(3)=3\}$ and $K=\{\alpha \in S_7:\alpha(5)=5\}$. Prove that $H\cong K$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Question:

> Let $H=\{\alpha \in S_7 :\alpha(3)=3\}$ and $K=\{\alpha \in S_7:\alpha(5)=5\}$. Prove that $H\cong K$

I'm not really able to do much here, I know I have to find some isomorphism but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: do you have an idea of a map that takes elements of one to the other?

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be you take the elements in $H$ and replace $5$ with $3$.

Comment: @AColoredReptile That is exactly the idea. Look at the element $g\in S_7$ defined by $g(3)=5$, $g(5)=3$ and $g(i)=i$ for $i=1,2,4,6,7$. What would happen if you take an element $\alpha\in H$ and you compute $g\alpha g^{-1}$?

Comment: @user647486 $g\alpha g^{-1}(i)=\alpha(i)$ for $i=1,2,4,6,7$ and $g\alpha g^{-1}(5)=5$ and $g\alpha g^{-1}(3)=\alpha(5)$. And this is an autorphism of $S_7$ so the restriction is an isomorphism. Right? Thanks.

Comment: $g\alpha g^{-1}$ is not an automorphism of $S_7$. It is an element of $S_7$. It is $\alpha\mapsto g\alpha g^{-1}$ the one that is (needs to be proven) and automorphism of $S_7$. What you checked is that if $\alpha$ was in $H$ then $g\alpha g^{-1}$ is in $K$.

Comment: @user647486 isn't this map $\phi_g$ the inner automorphism induced by $g$? Where $g=(35)$?

Comment: Howdy!  Why did you delete this post:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150693/fix-k-in-mathbbz-and-g-in-g-a-group-the-equation-xk-g-has-the-same-n?  I was having some fun writing up an answer!  Cheers!

Comment: @Robert Lewis No one had responded and the comment basically gave me the solution. Its been undeleted.

Comment: @AColoredReptile:  OK, thanks a lot!  I'm not sure my answer will be all that great, but I appreciate the chance.

Comment: @AColoredReptile Yes, that's right.

Comment: Can someone kindly explain what $\alpha(k)$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $S_7$ is defined as the permutations of the set $\overline{1,7}:=\{1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7\}$ under composition of functions. There is nothing special about the symbols from $1$ to $7$ here.

What each of $H$ and $K$ do is gather together all elements of $S_7$ that *fix* some element of $\overline{1,7}$; respectively, $3$ and $5$. The structure of each of these subgroups is thus the same as the other. Hence they are isomorphic.

More formally, here is a hint: conjugate by $(35)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$The general fact behind this is the following.

> Suppose the group $G$ acts on the set $\Omega$. Let $x \in \Omega$ and $a \in G$. Then $a G_{x} a^{-1} = G_{a(x)}$.

Here $G_{x} = \Set{ g \in G : g(x) = x }$ is the stabiliser of $x$ in $G$.

Proof. 
\begin{align}
G_{a(x)}
&=
\Set{ g \in G : g a(x) = a(x) }\\
&=
\Set{ g \in G : a^{-1} g a(x) = x } \\
&=
\Set{ g \in G : a^{-1} g a \in G_{x} } \\
&=
a G_{x} a^{-1}.
\end{align}